# $_FILE não definida

Tags: php, html

Estou com um problema na variável global $_FILE. É a minha primeira vez utilizando ele, e logo dou de cara com esse problema. Defino o enctype, tudo certo, mas mostra que a variável não existe...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="arquivo">
    <input type="submit" name="upload">
</form>
<br>
<br>
<strong>$_FILE</strong><br>
<br>
<?php var_dump($_FILE); ?>
<br>
<br>
<strong>$_POST</strong><br>
<br>
<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**mesmo após escolher um arquivo, o $_FILE não funciona**

Comment: verifique se foi iniciada primeiro com `if (isset($_FILE['arquivo'])) { }`

Comment: ja tentei isso, mas posso tentar denovo

Comment: não funcionou..

Comment: tem um `<?php var_dump($_FILE); ?>` não deveria ser assim

Comment: olá, ja tentei do modo de verificação com isset() e etc, mas o erro persiste, ele nem chega a conhecer a variavel $_FILE

Comment: Olha só passou desapercebido é `$_FILES` pelo menos foi resolvido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O nome correcto será `$_FILES` em vez de `$_FILE`. Podes consultar [aqui a documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.files.php).

Comment: se for isso eu juro que largo o PHP da vida kkkk...

Comment: devo excluir o post ?

Comment: Não, o *method* deve mesmo ser `post` e mantém também o *enctype* como `multipart/form-data`, só assim o upload irá funcionar.

Comment: o post eu digo a publicação da duvida em si.

Comment: Acredito que possa acontecer a outras pessoas, e pode ser útil se pesquisarem no google e encontrarem esta resposta. Parece algo simples, mas eu já perdi a conta a muitos anos da quantidade de pequenos erros que me custaram horas a procurar uma solução :)